# "IF" statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, division, rating

I am making an app that you can vote things, I have a table that contains "rating" that goes from 0 to 100 and that contains "votes" too, which represents the number of votes. I am using:

```
UPDATE maincategory SET rating='75'/votes
```

But when nobody else have voted yet, then the votes are obviously "0". And this makes "75/0" (Division with "0"). How can I make an "If" statement or something else that verifies if that thing have "0" votes yet and not divide with "votes" (Because they're "0")?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: My vote logic doesn't make much sense, I have seen this now... Sorry, what must I make to correct this? Maybe add all ratings together and divide with the number of votes?

Comment: Would you like the rating to be '75' when there are 0 votes?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Comment: @Fusseldieb Why would that be great? Why would something start at 75%?

Comment: "75" is a variable in my program, but i'm writing here with "75" for you guys to understand it better ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run it on the rows that have votes.

```
UPDATE maincategory SET rating='75'/votes WHERE votes>0
```

Leave the others at a default of `0` or `NULL` rating and handle that in your app.

Also, the `'75'/votes` bit sounds a bit off to me. With one vote, it'll have a rating of 75. With two votes, it'll have a rating of 37.5. Votes typically wouldn't *decrease* a rating.

Typically, the new rating would be set like so (this is pseudocode, not valid SQL):

```
rating = ((current_rating * current_vote_count) + new_rating) / (current_vote_count + 1)
```

Comment: But your code only performs the vote, when they're more that 0 votes... I want that the first person can rate too.

Comment: @Fusseldieb Your rating logic doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "Votes typically wouldn't decrease a rating"... Oh, a error on my side '-'

Comment: Then how can I add all ratings together and divide per number of votes?

Comment: Psuedocode: `rating = ((current_rating * current_vote_count) + new_rating) / (current_vote_count + 1)`

Comment: I am confused now... How can I push the rating from the table, add '75' to it, divide with the number of votes and then update the table?

Comment: @Fusseldieb If the new rating is `50`, you'd do `UPDATE maincategory SET rating=(((rating * votes) + 50) / (votes + 1))`

Comment: Oh, this seems great. I will test it and then reply you here. Thanks.

Comment: Can I use `UPDATE maincategory SET rating=(((rating * votes) + 50) /MAX(1,votes)))`?

Comment: @Fusseldieb Do the math. With one existing vote of 75, that'd be `((75*1)+50)/1` which is incorrect. With two existing votes of 75, that'd be `((75*2)+50)/2` which is also incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I have do the math and its obvious. It must be (votes+1)

Comment: 50=((50 * 1)+100) / 1+1  >  50=(50+100) / 2  >  50=150/2  >  50=75  >  75

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the rating to be `75` if there are 0 votes, you can use:

```
UPDATE maincategory SET rating=75/MAX(1,votes)
```

That will ensure that there is always at least one 'vote' to divide by. Basically it forces the 0 votes case to be evaluated the same as the 1 vote case.

Comment: Great, but I have realized that I have a error on my side. How can I sum all ratings together and divide per number of votes?

Answer (score 0):

To offer a third answer using a CASE statement (equivalent to an IF):

```
UPDATE maincategory SET rating= CASE WHEN votes=0 THEN 0 ELSE '75'/votes END
```

This will set the value of `rating` to 0 when `votes` is `0`

As an IF statement:

```
UPDATE maincategory SET rating= if(votes=0, 0,'75'/votes)
```

Comment: Sorry, an error on my side. How can I add all ratings together and divide per number of votes?

Comment: You want all of the `rating` on the `maincategory` table to have the same value?

Comment: Are you actually looking to store that value. Could you not just `SELECT Sum(Rating)/Sum(Votes) FROM maincategory` It doesn't make much sense to store those results back in that same table.

Comment: No, the "75" is a variable of the actual rating on my side. I'm only writing 75 here to you understand better.

Comment: Maybe sum all together with: `UPDATE maincategory SET rating= if(votes=0, 1, SELECT (Rating+'75')/votes)` ?